# R: quick way to systematically delete rows like this?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a single column.

There are 620 rows. The first 31 rows we label class "A", the next 31 rows we label "class B", and so on. There are therefore 20 classes.

What I want to do is quite simple to explain but I need help coding it.

In the first iteration, I want to delete all rows that correspond to the last row for each class. That is, delete the last "A class" row, then delete the last "B class row", and so on.  This iteration, and all others, have to be performed, since I intend to do something else with the newly created dataset.

In the second iteration, I want to delete all rows that correspond to the last TWO rows for each class.  So, delete the last two rows for "A class", last two rows for "B class" and so on.

In the third iteration, delete the last three rows for each class. And so on.

In the final iteration, we delete the last 30 rows for each class. Meaning basically we only keep 1 row for each observation, the first one.

What's a quick way to put this into R code? I know I need to use a for loop and carefully pick some index to remove, but how?

EXAMPLE

```
column
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
```

If above is our original data frame, then in the first iteration, we should be left with

```
column
A1
A2
B1
B2
```

and so on.

Comment: Are each of the groups exactly the same size? If so, you could do `df[seq_len(nrow(df)) %% 31 < 30, ]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm making it simple here and use n=3 instead of n=31 with this dummy data set

```
n <- 3
dummy <- c(rep("A", n), rep("B", n), rep("C", n))

> dummy
[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

Now, the trick is to use boolean indices to pick which values to keep per iteration and combine this with the feature that R will repeat an index vector as many time as needed for a short vector to match a longer vector.

This function creates a mask of which elements in a group should be picked

```
make_mask <- function(to_keep, n)
    c(rep(TRUE, to_keep), rep(FALSE, n - to_keep))
```

It just gives you a boolean vector

```
> make_mask(2, 3)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

We can use it in a function that picks the element for an iteration:

```
pick_subset <- function(to_keep) dummy[make_mask(n - to_keep, n)]
```

Now, you can use this in a loop or an `lapply` to get the elements you need per iteration.

```
iterations <- iterations <- lapply(0:(n-1), pick_subset)
```

will give you this

```
> iterations
[[1]]
[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

If it is more to your taste to use 1:n in the `lapply`, simply adjust `make_mask` to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dat%>%mutate(grp=sub("\\d","",column))%>%
       group_by(grp)%>%
        slice(-n())%>%
      ungroup()%>%select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  column
   <chr>
1     A1
2     A2
3     B1
4     B2
```

data:

```
dat=read.table(header = T,stringsAsFactors = F,text="column
A1
           A2
           A3
           B1
           B2
           B3")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is still another way. Assuming the codes are all grouped and sorted as you show, use the `table` function to obtain the number of codes in the column. Each value in the `cumsum` of `table` happens to correspond to the index of the last item in each sequence. The `indexes` variable is augmented by 1 each time through the loop. The `y` variable is created by removing the rows indexed by `indexes`. (It doesn't matter that `indexes` is unsorted.) You just do what you need to with `y`. Here's the code with an example data.frame:

```
N <- 31
dat <-data.frame(x=c(rep("A",31),rep("B",31),rep("C",31),rep("D",31),rep("E",31)))
t.x <- cumsum(table(dat$x))
for (i in 1:(N-1)) {
    if (i == 1){
        indexes <- t.x
    } else {
        indexes = c(indexes,t.x-i)
    }
   y <- dat$x[-indexes]
   print(table(y))
}
```

The `print(table(y))` will show that the count of each code will decrease as required.

```
 y
 A  B  C  D  E 
30 30 30 30 30 
 y
 A  B  C  D  E 
29 29 29 29 29
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution with data.table package

Because you know exactly how many items are in each class as well as how many classes exist in the data, the following simple solution works:

#### Import packages and generate some test data:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(data.table) 

A = rep('A', 3) 
B = rep('B', 3) 
C = rep('C', 3)
val = rep(1:3, 3)

DT = data.table(class=c(A,B,C), val=val)
```

This loop simply iterates as many times as there are items in each of your so called "classes". With each iteration we subset an increasingly small portion of the original data with the `.SD[1:(4-i)]` portion of code. Be sure to set a value (4 in this case) that is one more that the number items in each class so that you don't receive an "index out of range error." The cool part is that data.table allows us to do this by a grouping vector ("class" in this case).

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  print(DT[, .SD[1:(4-i)], by = class])  # edit as needed to save copies
}
```

#### Output:

```
   class val
1:     A   1
2:     A   2
3:     A   3
4:     B   1
5:     B   2
6:     B   3
7:     C   1
8:     C   2
9:     C   3
   class val
1:     A   1
2:     A   2
3:     B   1
4:     B   2
5:     C   1
6:     C   2
   class val
1:     A   1
2:     B   1
3:     C   1
```